# Why python's findall does not return all cases in this regular expression?

Tags: python

This is my text:

```
import {
    SiteContext,
    get,
} from 'Base'
import {
    Brands,
    Courses,
    CtaSection,
    Download,
    Hero,
    Newsletter,
    Posts,
    Stats,
    Teachers,
    Features,
    Testimonials,
} from 'Index'

const Index = () => {
```

And this is my python code to get the list of named imports:

```
imports = re.findall("^import\s*\{([^\}]*)}", Global.content)
for item in imports:
    print(item)
```

But all I get is this:

```
    SiteContext,
    get,
```

Why do I not get the other part too? I tested my regex with regex101.com and it works just fine there.

Comment: that ^ matches the start of the string, to make it match the start of a line use multiline mode

Comment: ... or remove `^`

Comment: if you want to mimic the behaviour you see in regex101, you need to add the MULTILINE flag (that is active by default there), `re.findall("^import\s*\{([^\}]*)}", text, re.MULTILINE)`